# getting "Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface</macro>'"

Tags: android, kotlin

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.northguide"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}
```

`

I'm getting the error:

> "Can't determine type for tag '?attr/colorSurface'"

when trying to build my android project in Android Studio.

Anyone can explain what's happening and how to solve this issue.
I just created the project using empty activity and tried to run the app to make sure everything is synced and I got this. I've done it before but the first time encountered a such error. I dunno if it's a bug in the update of Android Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and I haven't yet managed to fully research why the issue exists. All I could find is that the main culprits are the following two lines in the dependencies section:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

There are two solutions you may implement:

1. Update Android Studio version to the latest one
2. Downgrade the versions of these two dependencies

Definitely, *Solution #1* is the best, but *Solution #2* worked for me (I didn't have the time to upgrade and 'possibly deal with new unknown issues'). I downgraded as follows:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case, the solution was to update Android Studio to last version (Electric Eel). I also updated Gradle and all dependencies and it worked for me.

Cheers!

Comment: Didn't know about formatting noise! Understood, thanks for your advice. I will definitely do it. Im new at responding.

Comment: True! Just done it. Looks better!

Comment: Would you update my answer if u think its a good one?